# Связь веб форм c#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

не получается получить доступ к компонентам другой формы.
Выдает ошибку на  Wfrm1.GetTextBoxName.Text: В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект.

```
WebForm1:
public TextBox GetTextBoxName 
{ get{return TextBoxName;}}
WebForm2:
static WebForm1 Wfrm1 = new WebForm1();
String S = Wfrm1.GetTextBoxName.Text;
```

Comment: Видимо, TextBoxName == null.

Comment: но он не пуст

Answer (score 2):

Это же асп.нет, страница живет всего лишь один запрос, у нее свой жизненный цикл и масса ньюансов. Что за "винформовский" подход? У вас не получится так сделать.